# How to Create a context menu which contains menu items in a Gridviewcolumn.celltemplate? Unable to get sample code to work

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have two button inside different columns in data grid view in WPF Application. That data grid view will load from DB. At same time , there will be a Location drop down menu item present in each row. I have five columns and the image shows the contents present in the last two column of my wpf application.

As we can see in the image, the arrow for the drop down is present in the **Location**. But when I press it, I do not see the sub menuitems as shown in the xaml code below.

```
<local:CustomListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Car" Width="Auto" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Car}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="House" Width="Auto" 
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding House}" />
        <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="60">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="Location" ToolTip="Click to see info">
                        <MenuItem Header="Start" Click="info_Click" 
                                  ToolTip="Shows the start route"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Final" Click="info_Click" 
                                  ToolTip="Show the final route"/>
                    </MenuItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn> 
    </GridView>
</local:CustomListView.View>
```

For some reason, I am unable to see the sub-items **Start** and **Final**. I am very new to this and would appreciate any help.

Thanks to all.

I am not able to understand how to add a

```
<local:CustomListView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>    
    //I want to be able to place the MenuItem in here
    </ContextMenu>
</local:CustomListView.ContextMenu>
```

I want to add something like this in the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` section.

Can someone guide me on how to do this. I have spent hours but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
To resolve the issue, nest it in a Menu tag.

             <Menu>
              <MenuItem Header="Location" ToolTip="Click to see info">
                    <MenuItem Header="Start" Click="info_Click" 
                              ToolTip="Shows the start route"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Final" Click="info_Click" 
                              ToolTip="Show the final route"/>
                </MenuItem>
              <Menu>
```